# Android statusbar overlay with ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I know that I can make the ActionBar overlay using `requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY)`
and can toggle/show the status bar in my screen (by switching between `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` and `FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN`).
This works great. However, I don't want my layout moving when I toggle the status bar.

I know that I can make the status bar "overlay" (albeit not transparently) the content using:

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN`
`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`

This works also great, except for the (expected) consequence that, when using an ActionBar, the ActionBar gets half cut off - half of it is under the status bar basically.

So I am wondering, is there a way to "move the ActionBar down" by the status bar's height in this case?
I know that in worse case, I can do this with a custom view that lives within the layout, but I rather not do this (want to benefit from the ActionBar).

thanks!

Comment: It isn't recommended to show toolbar whilst hiding the status bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so apparently, you can do this in Jellybean.  google includes two examples in the api docs.  here is a link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility%28int%29

summary:
use `setSystemUiVisibility` on a view to toggle visibility (on jellybean+).

Comment: How can this be achieved in ICS, any idea?

Comment: without using your own actionbar (custom implementation that doesn't set in the window decoration area), i don't know if this is doable.  the closest you can get is David Scott's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It's not perfect, but this is how I have achieved what you want:

In onCreate:

> getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Then:

```
private void hideStatusBar() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);

}

private void showStatusBar() {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}
```

I also have a style on the activity with the following:

```
 <style name="readingStyle" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
     <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>  
     <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>       
 </style>
```

Your activity will shift down when the status bar shows, but I don't think it's too noticeable.

Comment: thanks David - unfortunately, this was already what i had - i was trying to prevent the activity from shifting down.  i guess the only way to do it is to use a custom layout as an actionbar and just set the clock to overlay instead of actually using a real actionbar :(

Comment: your method `hideStatusBar()` works more robust than `setSystemUiVisibility` in conjunction with the ActionBar from compatibility package

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont make it in the Manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

than you have no statusbar and more space for the Actionbar??

Comment: thanks, but since this is a reading app, i want the user to know the time when they tap the screen, and want my layout to be full screen otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Put this method in onCreate() method activity:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

refer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041425/1233979)