# How do i start google maps at my location

Tags: android, eclipse, maps

i am able to enable google maps but it starts at the default 0,0 latitude and longitude. Currently using eclipse.

Comment: you are talking abt google maps app installed on your device..or you have done a code for a map..

Comment: @MeenalSharma i have done the code for a map

Comment: then you have to write the code to get your location..and then you can set it on google map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these two links helps you to get your current location...

javapapers.com/android/get-current-location-in-android/

[How to show my Current location in Google Map in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885364/how-to-show-my-current-location-in-google-map-in-android)

and if you have done the code to get location then simply set it using

```
     mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lat, long))
    .title("My Location"));
```